# Get text in between two h2 headers using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to grab the text that comes after Description and before the Next Header.

I know that:

```
In [8]: soup.findAll('h2')[6]
Out[8]: <h2>Description</h2>
```

However, I don’t know how to grab the actual text. The problem is I have multiple links to do this on. 
Some have the p:

```
                                         <h2>Description</h2>

  <p>This is the text I want </p>
<p>This is the text I want</p>   
                                        <h2>Next header</h2>
```

But, some don’t:

```
>                                       <h2>Description</h2>
>                        This is the text I want                 
> 
>                                       <h2>Next header</h2>
```

Also on each one with the p, I can’t just do soup.findAll(‘p’)[22] because on some the ‘p’ is at 21 or 20.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check for `NavigableString` to check if the next sibling is a text node or `Tag` to check if it is an element.

Break the loop if your next sibling is an header.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import requests

example = """<h2>Description</h2><p>This is the text I want </p><p>This is the text I want</p><h2>Next header</h2>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'html.parser')
for header in soup.find_all('h2'):
    nextNode = header
    while True:
        nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
        if nextNode is None:
            break
        if isinstance(nextNode, NavigableString):
            print (nextNode.strip())
        if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
            if nextNode.name == "h2":
                break
            print (nextNode.get_text(strip=True).strip())
```

Comment: That works, but grabs all the text, when I only need it between the two headers. I'll try to modify what you gave me to see if it works, thanks!