# Parse tables under h1 tag with BeautifulSoup and store in df

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract tables from multiple websites under a h1 'Tables' header. Each website has multiple h1 headers, but the 'Tables' one is consistent across all sites. Each table also comes with an h2 header which differs from site to site although I have managed to extract them into a list.

My current code parses all tables, even the ones that come before the h1 'Tables' header. How can I exclude those tables? The html is similar to the one below:

```
<h2>I don't care about this table</h2>
<table class="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>Key A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A value I don't want</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1>Tables</h1>
<p> A description I don't care about </p>
<h2>First good table</h2>
<table class="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>Key B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A value I want</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<h2>Second good table</h2>
<table class="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>Key C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A value I want</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My current approach:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.body, features="lxml")
headers = [tags.text for tags in soup.find_all(["h1", "h2"])]

try:
    # Find h2 table headers under h1 'Tables' header
    target_index = headers.index("Tables")
    table_headers = headers[target_index + 1 :]

except ValueError:
    print("Page doesn't contain tables")

# This includes all tables. How do we make sure we only include those under the 'Tables' header?
tables_raw = [[[cell.text for cell in row("th") + row("td")] for row in table("tr")]for table in soup("table")]

# Create dfs and assign a name
tables_df = [pd.DataFrame(table) for table in tables_raw]
tables_and_names = list(zip(table_headers, tables_df))
```

I did have a look [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935973/how-to-extract-html-table-following-a-specific-heading), but can't figure out how to get the df output that I currently have. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector with `~`:

```py
for table in soup.select("h1:-soup-contains(Tables) ~ table"):
    for row in table.select("tr"):
        print(*[td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")])
```

Prints:

```
Key B
A value I want
Key C
A value I want
```

---

Or without CSS selectors:

```py
h1 = soup.find("h1", text="Tables")
for table in h1.find_next_siblings("table"):
    for row in table.select("tr"):
        print(*[td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")])
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej Kesely Is there a difference between `find(..., text="tables")` and `find(..., string="tables")`? Both works. Is `text` more greedy?

Comment: @cards They're equal (according to the documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument - last sentence). I should probably use `string=` from now on...

Comment: ok. But if you try to access to a tag string have different effects, right?

Comment: sorry for bothering you... There are also reference of the `.string` Tag attributes in the doc. I aslo tried the following: `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<div>Hi</div>', 'lxml')` `print(hasattr(soup.div, 'string'))`
`print('string' in dir(soup.find('div')))` and they return True. Why are you saying that `.string` doesn't exist?

Comment: By me print `Hi`. Using bs4 4.9.3

Comment: @cards Weird. If you have some other tag inside the `<div>` (e.g. `<div>Hi <span>World</span></div>`) It prints `None`. That's why I use only `.text`

Comment: Ahaha yes, now is None! That's why before I mentioned if `.text` was "greedy"! Thanks again for your advice and reference to the doc! [also `.get_text()` is "greedy"]

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
header = soup.find('h1')
for sibling in header.next_siblings:
    if sibling.name == 'table':
        do_stuff()
```

Comment: I can isolate the header, but it still pulls everything after the if statement.

Comment: with the html sample you gave it only grabs the two tables under the header. that's what you asked for

Comment: What I meant is that ```sibling``` looks as expected in the if statement and doesn't pull the table above h1. But somehow it still gets pulled with ```tables_raw```. Not sure why though.